# how do i display images in this script in a specific div with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

Im using JQInstapics to get a feed from Instagram (http://projects.craftedpixelz.co.uk/jqinstapics/).

I want to change the way the resulting pictures are displayed. Im using fullpage.js (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) and would like to use the slider to display each picture individually. In order to show the pictures in the slider, the pictures have to be displayed in a `<div>` with the `class="slide" (<div class="slide"><img></div>)`.

So Im not that good with jQuery (yet) so Im having trouble getting the way its displaying the pictures to work the want it to. Ive treid various way and none of them work, I always get just a row of pictures.

Here is the entire JQInstapics script: Ive marked where I made changes I thought would work.

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.jqinstapics = function (options) {

            // Defaults
            var defaults = {
                "user_id": null,
                "access_token": null,
                "count": 10
            };                      

            var o = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function () {

              // Vars
              var elem = $(this),

                url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + o.user_id + "/media/recent?access_token=" + o.access_token + "&count=" + o.count + "&callback=?";

                // Get the images   
                $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                    $.each(data.data, function (i, val) {

// created the div var to try and give the image the div container it needs to be a slide. wanted to append it as the first elemet to the elem var that creates the display.

                        var div = $("<div class='slide'>").appendTo(elem),
                            li = $("<li/>").appendTo(div),
                            a = $("<a/>", {"href": val.link, "target": "_blank"}).appendTo(li),

       // added the </div> to try and close out the slide div.

                            img = $("<img/></div>", {"src": val.images.thumbnail.url}).appendTo(a);


                        if (val.caption){
                            a.attr("title", val.caption.text);
                        }
                    });
                });

                if(o.user_id == null || o.access_token == null){
                  elem.append("<li>Please specify a User ID and Access Token, as outlined in the docs.</li>");
                }

            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Take into account that you would need first to create the needed structure for fullpage.js ,and then initialize fullPage.js ONCE the structure has been created (and not before). I don't see in your code any reference to fullPage.js initialization.

Comment: I tried to recreate the whole app/page on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LsL0uwc/1/ with all the js, html, etc.. Youll see that the images in the #instagram div are in a line, not in sliders like i would like them to be (even though the code shows something that looks like it should be producing sliders).